# How to install rpm to /usr/bin instead of /opt/app-root/bin

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile, centos7, rpm

I'm trying to create rpm package for Centos7.
So I create Dockerfile from Centos7 image and build rpm inside.
It build successfully, but there is one problem:
when I try to use this rpm as package in other Dockerfiles it installs into `/opt/app-root/bin` when I need to install it to `usr/bin`.

Here is my Dockerfile for building rpm (I also install it inside just to check it works):

```
FROM centos/python-27-centos7:latest

USER root

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install rpm-build -y

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .

RUN bash -c "pip install --upgrade pip"

RUN git clone https://github.com/klbostee/typedbytes.git
RUN bash -c "cd typedbytes && python setup.py install"

RUN bash -c "pip install -r requirements.txt"

RUN git clone https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo

RUN bash -c "cd dumbo && python setup.py \
    --command-packages=pypi2rpm.command bdist_rpm2 \
    --binary-only \
    --tmppath /tmp/ \
    --dist-dir=. \
    --no-autoreq \
    --name=python27-dumbo \
    --python=python"

RUN cd dumbo && yum install *.rpm -y
CMD ["bash"]
```

I use `docker run -ti -v ...`  after that and copy rpm from mounted volume.
After that I try to use this rpm in another Dockerfile, it installs it successfully, but can't find command to use it : `no such file or directory`
I suppose it installs rpm to the wrong path and then cannot find it.

I suppose my problem is using `USER root` - look like that is why it try to install it to `/opt/root/` but I don't know how to change it.

How to install it to `usr/bin`? Do I need to create another user inside Docker? Or what?

Comment: if your final goal is to create a docker image with your software installed, I would skip the creation of an intermediate rpm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start to think that my problem is a wrong image chosen to built app.
I tried to use another one:

```
FROM centos:centos7
```

And install python to it manually. And this solves the problem - in this image I have root privileges when writing Dockerfile and my library installs to `/usr/bin` as I wish.
So the solution is:

```
FROM centos:centos7
MAINTAINER The CentOS Project <cloud-ops@centos.org>

RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install epel-release; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python-pip; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install rpm-build
RUN yum -y install git, which


RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools

RUN mkdir app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app 

RUN git clone https://github.com/klbostee/typedbytes.git
RUN cd typedbytes && python setup.py install
...
```

and so on.